# GAE/J changes Content-Type from JSON to HTML when the status code is 4xx

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I wrote a Web API in Java (JAX-RS by Jersey) which returns "403 Forbidden" with JSON.

```html
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
...

{"resultCode":"..."}
```

It works on the local GAE dev server as expected. However, **on the real GAE, the content type is changed from JSON to HTML**.

```html
HTTP/1.1. 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
</body></html>
```

How can I prevent GAE from changing the content type and the entity body?

---

**Additional Information**

My endpoint does not throw any exception. It returns a Response instance. The code snippet below is a test endpoint. On the local GAE dev server, this endpoint returns JSON. On the real GAE, it returns HTML. Too much of a good thing.

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint
{
    @GET
    public Response get()
    {
        return Response
                .status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity("{\"id\":1}")
                .build();
    }
}
```

---

**Additional Information 2**

I wrote a simpler example code like below. **This code returns JSON even on the real GAE!** What's the difference?

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setStatus(400);
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I read Jersey's source code and intuited this answer.

Setting "**jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError**" (one of Jersey's [server configuration properties](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html#appendix-properties-server)) to true solved the issue.

The following is an excerpt from my new web.xml.

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
      ......
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: When response.sendError(code) is invoked, the servlet container handles the response by providing an error page defined in your web.xml, or if none a default error page. That is, sendError always results in an html resource. The dev-server and production server handle these differently (i.e. the dev server doesn't use error pages defined in web.xml). My guess is you have jersey configured to hand control over to the servlet when you set status on the jersey response. The configuration you put in here probably changes that.

Comment: +1 Thanks, works for me.
I just got the same problem with my colleague, and your response save us hours.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define your own exception mapper and payload extensions in your service context file:

```
<jaxrs:server id="my-resources" address="/some-context-path">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="my-resource-1" />
        <ref bean="my-resource-2" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
        <ref bean="my-custom-exception-mapper" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

my-custom-exception-mapper implements ExceptionMapper, ResponseExceptionMapper.  Something like this is a good start:  http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/06/15/apache-cxf-exception-handler-for-jaxrs-rest/

Comment: Thank you for the information, but my endpoint does not throw any exception, so exception mappers would not catch anything. The point is in that the local GAE dev server and the real GAE behave differently. I want to know how to prevent GAE from doing unnecessary things.

Comment: I was under the impression that the 403 was an exception you were throwing, thanks for posting code samples.  I believe I got around the HTML issue by setting the extension mappings that JAX-RS was allowed to use for the response content-type:  

`<entry key="json" value="application/json"/>`

(as shown above)

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned solution without web.xml may look like:

```
new ResourceConfig()
       .property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
```